# Using local function in Linq queries in Entity Framework Core

Tags: c#, linq, entity-framework-core

I have written Linq query in Entity Framework Core like this:

```
Func<decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal, decimal> f = (a, b, c, d) => a + b + c + d;

var result = dbcontext.DailyStats
                    .Where(p => p.Year == 2020)
                    .Sum(p => f(p.field1, p.field2, p.field3, p.field4))
```

However, this gives the following exception:

> System.InvalidOperationException: 'The LINQ expression 'Invoke(__f_1, [EntityShaperExpression].field1, [EntityShaperExpression].field2, [EntityShaperExpression].field3, [EntityShaperExpression].field4)
> ' could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated, or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either AsEnumerable(), AsAsyncEnumerable(), ToList(), or ToListAsync(). See https://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?linkid=2101038 for more information.'

How can I solve this?

Comment: @PavelAnikhouski Yes, I have already tried. But I couldn't find a solution.

Comment: you would need to use an `Expression`. This is a little more complicated when you want to feed it into entity. But you don't really need to run the sum on the sql server side. You could fetch the data and run the `Sum` method on the client side/your machine. Simply put a `ToList()` after the Where clause

Comment: [How can I call a local function inside a LINQ query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13105518/how-can-i-call-a-local-function-inside-a-linq-query) and [How can I call local method in Linq to Entities query?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18714821/how-can-i-call-local-method-in-linq-to-entities-query)

Comment: @MongZhu I have already used Expression. However, the same exception occurs.

Comment: could you post your expression attempt?

Comment: in my opinion the suggested duplicate is either not fitting, or not enough. It clearly is possible in this case to translate this local function into sql if you write the function correctly. The solution to fetch all data into memory and then calculate the sum is a crude workaround in this case.

Answer (score 3):

Actually if you look what `Sum` expects as input parameter you will see: `Expression<Func<YouDataTable, int?>> selector`. So let us build one of those:

```
Expression<Func<DailyStat, int?> f = (p) => p.field1 + p.field2 + p.field3 + p.field4;
```

Now you need only to pass the `f` into the Sum function. There is no need to call it, it will be called automatically:

```
var result = dbcontext.DailyStats
                .Where(p => p.Year == 2020)
                .Sum(f);
```

And this is how the translated sql looks like (I changed the column names a little, since I tested it on my machine, and I used only 3 columns)

```
SELECT SUM([t0].[col1] + [t0].[col2] + [t0].[col3]) AS [value]
FROM [myTable] AS [t0]
WHERE DATEPART(Year, [t0].[timestamp]) = @p0
-- @p0: Input Int (Size = -1; Prec = 0; Scale = 0) [2020]
```

Comment: Thank you. I tried this, and got exactly the desired result. And I also tried this on GroupBy. However, this was not possible with GroupBy. Is there another way to use it in GroupBy?

Comment: @jrchs you wanted to sum over the groups? This sounds like an additional problem. You should post a new question and post there the groupby query that you have tried out.

Comment: @jrchs if my answer helped you to solve your problem, you can consider to mark it as accepted, even if the question is closed as duplicate. This will help also future readers

Answer (score 0):

Your problem is that your function is meant to run on the client, whereas because you haven't called ToList() yet, Entity Framework is trying to translate it to SQL. But it doesn't know how to because your custom function isn't a built-in EF Core function.

Call .ToList() on your query before you perform the Sum() operation. Or make do without the function if you want it to happen on the database.

Comment: If you use ToList(), all records are fetched to the client and Sum() is performed. I want to do Sum() in DB.

Comment: Yes, I know that. The problem is that EF Core doesn't know how to translate your function to SQL. You would have to make do without your function if you want to run SUM on the DB.

Comment: Is it impossible to convert a local function to an sql query?

Comment: @jrchs "Is it impossible to convert a local function to an sql query? " yes and no. Yes because `Sum` does not want a `Func` but an Expression. and no, it is possible if you use an Expression. Have a look at my answer. It solves your problem

Answer (score 0):

I worked last week on LINQ issue and looks to me it is very similar to that problem.
As the message suggested:
Could not be translated. Either rewrite the query in a form that can be translated.
or switch to client evaluation explicitly by inserting a call to either:
(a) AsEnumerable(), (b) AsAsyncEnumerable(), (c) ToList(),  or (d) ToListAsync().

Use the the above functions before the sum and see if you able to get the desired result.
Also datatype at db side also matters.

```
  var result = dbcontext.DailyStats
           .Where(p => p.Year == 2020)
            .AsEnumerable() 
          .Sum(p => f(p.field1, p.field2, p.field3, p.field4))
```

Comment: Use of `.AsEnumerable()` is expensive because it will return all records from DailyStats where condition `Year == 2020` satisfies.